# Getters incorporating Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, exoplayer

Libraries like ExoPlayer require that all calls to it are on the main thread. In this case, I have a getter that fetches a property from ExoPlayer, but it SHOULD be from the main thread.

I tried using `Handler`, but there is no way to wait for it...

```kotlin
    val currentTrackIndex: Int
        get() {
            var result = -1

            handler.post {
                result = exoPlayer.currentIndex
            }

            return result
        }
```

... the result would always be -1.

The only way I found that works is to use `runBlocking`. However, this doesn't seem like it should be used for production:

```
val currentTrackIndex: Int
    get() {
        return runBlocking {
            return@runBlocking exoPlayer.currentIndex
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to block the main thread inside getters?

NOTE: All of these calls are inside a Service.

NOTE 2: Even though I need to block the main thread (which might raise red flags), getting the property is as instantaneous as it can be. ExoPlayer is just strange in how it operates.

Comment: why can't you use a callback?

Answer (score 0):

Create an application class, make a static Context field in it and then use `Context.getMainLooper()` in your Handler, I think it will solve your problem.